# create button with text on left and image/icon on right on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to create button with image on react. 
i define the code

```
 <button id='a' value='value1' >
    <img="image.png" align="right|middle"/>
    "myButton"
 </button>
```

but the problem is

1. i see the image in different align from the text 
   i mean that the text and the image are not in the same hight and i can't make tham look good
2. i not sure this is best prectice to do it -  ( i must store the button id and also the button value on some way )

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Put the text `"myButton"` inside a span and apply `className`s to both the tags `span` and `img`. Change the positions by using the CSS.

Comment: @AkhilP : thanks .. i still learn web deb - can you please show example of what do you mean ?

Comment: i still can't make them to be same hight and

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/316pm95qym

Comment: Use flex for much better way approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox to make alignment easier (`align-items` is useful - here I set it to `center`). Children of a flex-container can change the order they appear using the `order` property.

Below is a toy example of a component that takes a single prop `align`, which determines whether the image goes before or after the text.

```js
const Button = ({ align }) => (
  <button className="my-button">
    <img className={align} src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
    click me
  </button>
)

ReactDOM.render(<div>
  <Button />
  <Button align="right" />
</div>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
.my-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. I have been looking for a solution like this. now I can use your code snippet to design Google, Facebook, Twitter and Github button.